# Navigation.PushAsync is not working inside User Control in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView in my ContentPage. Inside ListView.ItemTemplate, I have user control. In user control, there are image buttons. On Click of ImageButton, I want to move another page but it's not working. The code is run without error but nothing happened. The same code of PushAsync is working from all other content pages but not in user control. Please help me in this regard to what should I do.

ListView Code inside ContentPage:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvPosts" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" 
IsVisible="False">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <controls:CardView/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

UserControl CardView:

```
<Frame  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"       
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.General"
         VerticalOptions="Start"         
         x:Class="MyApp.Controls.CardView">

<Frame.Content>
    <Grid Padding="10" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <Label                              
            Grid.Column="0" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
            Grid.Row="0"                    
            Text="{Binding Title}"                     
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            TextColor="#479774"
            FontSize="Medium" 
            Style="{StaticResource DefaultFontStyle}"
            Opacity="0.8">
        </Label>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <ImageButton
                x:Name="imgPdf"
                Source="pdf.png"                    
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Clicked="imgPdf_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <ImageButton 
                x:Name="imgContent"
                Source="document2.png"
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Clicked="imgContent_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
            <ImageButton
                x:Name="imgSummary"
                Source="document.png"
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Clicked="imgSummary_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
            <ImageButton
                x:Name="imgVideo"
                Source="video1.png"
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                Clicked="imgVideo_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>            
    </Grid>
</Frame.Content>
</Frame>
```

And Code behind on ImageButton:

```
    private async void imgVideo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Post post = this.BindingContext as Post;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new WebViewPage(post));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could only invoke  the method `Navigation.PushAsync` in a **ContentPage** .  In your case , **CardView** is a subclass of a Frame , so it will never work .

The best solution is to invoke the method in Code Behind (ViewModel or ContentPage) . Since you had used Custom View . It would be better to  handle the logic by using Data-binding .

If you do want to invoke the method in CardView, you could define a property in **App** and pass the current Navigation from ContentPage .

#### in App.xaml.cs

```
public INavigation navigation { get; set; }
```

#### in ContentPage

Note : You need to invoke the following lines in each ContentPage .

```
public xxxContentPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   var app = App.Current as App;
   app.navigation = this.Navigation;
}
```

#### in CardView

```
var app = App.Current as App;

var navigation = app.navigation;

navigation.PushAsync(xxx);
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer isn't quite correct, and makes some assumptions.  Navigation is available and can be used by any Xamarin Forms component that inherits NavigableElement and has a NavigationPage as an ancestor in its parental hierarchy.  It's not limited to ContentPage by any means.  Internal to Xamarin Forms, NavigableElements access their ancestral NavigationPage's Navigation stack via a series of internal NavigationProxy classes that get set and bound to their parent's NavigationProxy when each element's parent is set.  Externally, we see these proxies as their interface type of INavigation, typically as the Navigation property of whatever element we're using.

ViewCell does not inherit NavigableElement (why, I'm not entirely sure, since it's parented to its container like any other component), and thus doesn't have a Navigation property.  In your case, your ViewCell contains another View, which *does* inherit NavigableElement, but because its parent (ViewCell) isn't a NavigableElement, the chain of NavigationProxies is broken.  Thus, you can try to make calls to Navigation on your CardView, but it's not hooked up to anything, and thus won't do anything.

The solution of directly accessing the Application's Navigation property (I assume the above poster meant Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation, as Application doesn't have a Navigation property itself) only works if your Application's MainPage is the *only* NavigationPage in your app.  However, this isn't guaranteed to be the case; for example, a TabbedPage component could contain its own NavigationPages for each of its tabs, and accessing Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation will only get you the NavigationProxy for navigating the MainPage.  ViewCells in a tabbed NavigationPage would be unable to navigate within their tab via this solution.

What you can do instead is something like this:

```
public MyViewCell : ViewCell
{
    private INavigation Navigation { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParentSet()
    {
        base.OnParentSet();

        Navigation = (Parent as NavigableElement)?.Navigation;
    }
}
```

Your ViewCell now has access to its parent's navigation stack, which you can do with as you please.  You could pass it into your cell's child View, if you wanted, or just do your navigation here.  Why ViewCell doesn't already do this under the hood, I don't fully understand.

Note: Depending on the CacheStrategy you set on your ListView (or whatever View component is using your ViewCell as a template), it's possible your custom ViewCell may be handed a null Parent from time to time, which would yield a null Navigation property.  Usually this shouldn't be a problem, as a null Parent generally indicates the cell isn't actively being displayed, but it's worth keeping in mind in case your custom ViewCell could potentially try to access Navigation without user input via some automated business logic.

Comment: This is such a simple and genius solution. I have a chat-style feature in my app and needed a way to display images in full screen on click. This did the trick perfectly. Thank you!!